# Using Predictive Model to Judge Performance?

Tags: predictive-models

Let's say I have a model that predicts a student's performance on the SAT based on a bunch of factors that a student doesn't have control over, like age, race, household income, family history, etc. Nothing that directly relates to performance is in the model (e.g. GPA, courses taken, scores on other tests, etc.). Let's also say the SAT is still out of 1600 -- I know it's changed but bear with me.

If my model predicts that "Student A" will get a 1200 but they actually get a 1000, is it fair to say that they under-performed and may need some kind of intervention? If the model predicts that "Student B" will get an 800 but they get a 1000, is it fair to say they over-performed? So even though both students got a 1000, it's more of a *problem* that Student A got a 1000 than it is that Student B got a 1000?

Is it legitimate to use this predictive model to "judge" whether a student is an over- or under-performer? Can we interpret the size and direction of the residual to reflect on that student in some way? To what extent can we give "credit" or "blame" to a student for under- or over-performing compared to a prediction?

Essentially what I'm trying to do is create a "moving bar" on which these students would be judged. So instead of all students being rewarded for having a score over 1000 and punished for having a score below 1000, each student would have their own unique "bar" (in the example above, Student A would be punished and Student B would be rewarded, even though they had the same score).

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "is it fair"? On the face of it, the model predicts 1200, the result is 1000, so the result is 200 less than the prediction.  There doesn't seem to be any question concerning that.  What, then, are you trying to get at?

Comment: What I'm trying to get at is the *judging* part of it. Like, can I say, "Hey, Student A, you *should* have done better than that, so we need to do some intervention", and "Student B, you performed better than predicted, so you're in good shape". My original question probably added important details, but I was afraid it had too many details for people to want to read, LOL. Sorry for the lack of clarity. I'll see if I can modify the question.

Comment: Since these differences compare a *student* to a *model*, it would seem rather one-sided to lay all blame or credit for under or overperformance on the student.  Why couldn't the model be wrong?  That consideration persuades me there may be a useful question here, especially if you could focus it a little more.

Comment: What evaluations of your model do you have? If predicting the exact score, how far off is its output from actual SAT scores?

Comment: @whuber, Yes, that is exactly what I'm trying to get at. That's a very good point about the model being wrong. But, in fact, I expect the model to be wrong because there are other, measurable factors that I could have included but intentionally did not because I want to be able to say, "Students like you are expected to get a 1000. You got an 800. Let's see where you can make improvements". Perhaps that's only appropriate if I use something like a KNN model?

Comment: @Upper_Case, this is purely theoretical at this point. And, in fact, the model I'm thinking about has nothing to do with SAT scores, but I don't think I'm allowed to share the actual content of what I'm thinking about because it's proprietary, haha!

Comment: You seem to be reading a whole lot more into your model than is actually there!  For instance, the meaning of "students like you" must be understood as something akin to "students in my study whose age, race, income, and family are like yours averaged 1000.  You got 800."  (I write "akin to" because you might not actually have seen any comparable students.)  It would seem logically impossible to support a conclusion that is any stronger than "your performance was less than the average of the students I studied whom I deemed comparable to you."

Comment: You also need to account for variability.  Your conclusions would likely differ between these two extreme cases: (1) for all relevant scores $y$, all students in your study predicted to score $y$ actually did score between $y-1$ and $y+1$ and (b) all students predicted to score $y$ actually scored between $y+1000$ and $y-1000$.  Without such information, you have little basis to assess just *how much* any particular score departs from a predicted value.

Comment: @Hadley That makes things more challenging, since context can make a huge difference both in methods and interpretation. Someone else can probably write a better answer than me, but in general you will need to assess the accuracy and precision of the model before it makes sense to assign *any* credit or blame for over- or under-performing the model's predictions. Do you have any such measures already, or do you still need to produce them?

Comment: @whuber, yes these are all really good points. I guess what I'm really trying to do is create a *fairer* bar to measure individuals on. So, imagine that currently all students are punished if they are below 1000 and rewarded if they are above 1000. I want to be able to say, "Hey this group of students can't be expected to perform as well as this group of students because of things outside of their control. Instead of comparing these students to 1000, we should raise or lower the bar". Can I make a different "bar" for each student, based on a predictive model?

Comment: Sure you can set different standards. That's precisely what the dialog about educational performance measures has been about in the US for at least 15 years: should you evaluate teachers based on what their class achieved compared to what would be expected of that class? If so, how do you determine what kind of performance is expected and how do you measure it? How do you avoid rewarding bad teachers or penalizing good ones due to variations in class performance beyond their control, including random variation?

Comment: @whuber, Yes, exactly! I knew there were folks out there thinking about this same type of issue. The teacher performance situation is very analogous to the situation I'm trying to solve here. I will try to do some research on what has been discussed in the dialog about educational performance measures -- I'm not really up on that (only familiar with the growth vs proficiency debate). If you happen to have any advice on where to look or some articles to read, I would be so grateful. You've already been tremendously helpful!

Comment: And the "including random variation" part is the part I'm most worried about dealing with. Let's say the outcome variable Y is due to factors A through G, as well as some random variation. A-C are completely outside of an individual's control but are measurable. D-G are a person's individual qualities that can be sorta measured by a proxy (abstract things like "grit" and "charisma"), but we don't have any data available. We build a model based on A-C. Can we say that if an individual differs from their prediction greatly, that it must have something to do with D-G? Or could it all be random?

Comment: If you build a model based on A-C only, then all variation has to be attributed to any other factors that are not included within the model. If you don't include D-G or any proxies for them, then it would seem you have no information to draw any conclusions about D-G at all.

Comment: @whuber, yes that's what I'm saying: "all variation has to be attributed to any other factors that are not included within the model": D-G are those factors! I'm not saying that D-G are some actual known factors that I chose not to include in my model, they represent "all other factors not included in my model". I have an *idea* of what some of them are based on previous studies, but they are really unknown.